# Add a Method to Object Array

Tags: java, reflection

I would like to fill a Method in an Array. But I have to do this in a strange way:

```
public class AssignFunctionalInterfaceTest {

    public void test() {
        TestEntity t = new TestEntity();

        // compiles
        Supplier<Integer> a = t::getB;
        Object[] b = new Object[] {"42", a};

        // compiles
        Object[] b2 = new Object[] {"42", (Supplier<Integer>) t::getB};

        // doesn't compile. Error message:
        // "The target type of this expression must be a functional interface"
        Object[] b3 = new Object[] {"42", t::getB};
    }


    public static class TestEntity {

        public Integer getB() {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I would really like to find a way to make the third assignment work. Any Ideas?

Comment: Why is "42" a value in the array? does it need to be? otherwise you could just create a `Supplier<Integer>[]` instead of `Object[]`

Comment: It's really about mixing things together. I see your point but it doesn't help me with my problem.

Comment: I could be wrong about this, but I think why it won't let you just place the method reference in the array is because it needs to be associated with `Supplier<>` in some way due to it changing the way that it is looked at by the compiler.  I think the `Supplier<>` class sets up a linkage between the pointer and the actual method for the compiler.

Comment: What's the compile error? Please edit it into the question.

Comment: Added compiler error to comment

Comment: As to why this _must_ be a compiler error: The method reference `t::getB` could also be a `Supplier<Object>` and this is not assignment compatible to a `Supplier<Integer>`. It is a different type. Without assignment to the wanted type (a functional interface, here) the compiler cannot infer the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same thing why you can not just write:

```
Object x = t::getB;
```

Creating object of lambda class is a syntactic sugar, and type is needed to be defined explicitly. For more information read [JLS, 15.13](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13)

Comment: Heavy stuff. You say no way around it? Is the cast the shortest way? I found out Supplier<?> also is enough.